# Tkinter Checkbox with Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, checkbox, tkinter

Newb Question:

I'm trying to create a Tkinter GUI where the checkboxes change the values in a dictionary.

For some reason, though when I click on any one of the checkboxes all of the other checkboxes are also toggled active and inactive. What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *

class test(object):

  def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
     self.frame = root
     self.frame.minsize(860, 265)
     self.dic_processlist = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0, 'e':0}

     self.chk1 = Checkbutton(text = "a", variable=self.dic_processlist['a'])
     self.chk1.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="w")
     self.chk2 = Checkbutton(text = "b", variable=self.dic_processlist['b'])
     self.chk2.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky="w")
     self.chk3 = Checkbutton(text = "c", variable=self.dic_processlist['c'])
     self.chk3.grid(row=6, column=3, sticky="w")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   app = test(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Tkinter Variables](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) instead of ordinary integers.

```
def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
    self.frame = root
    self.frame.minsize(860, 265)
    self.dic_processlist = {letter: IntVar() for letter in "abcde"}
```